# 'amsmath' option 'tbtags' not working in beamer

Tags: beamer, amsmath

I would like to use the `tbtags` option with `amsmath` multiline equations in `beamer`. Unfortunately, I cannot get it to work. Here is a minimal example that works using `article`, but does not work with `beamer`.

```
\documentclass[amsmath={tbtags}]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        M &= \text{first line} \\ &\qquad \text{second line}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I can't find anything in the `beamer` docs indicating that this should not work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Using the `noamsthm` option, beamer does not load `amsmath` by default and you can load it with whatever options you like.

```
\documentclass[noamsthm]{beamer}

\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        M &= \text{first line} \\ &\qquad \text{second line}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That did it! Thank you! By the way, `beamer` does load `amsmath`. :-)

Comment: @GaryL.Gray Beamer only loads amsmath if the option `noamsthm` is not given, see user guide p. 121

Answer (score 1):

you can your write mwe correctly as follows:

```
\documentclass[tbtags]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        M &= \text{first line} \\ &\qquad \text{second line}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @samcarter, indeed. number is not positioned correctly. i will correct my answer accordingly asap.

Comment: The difference is really hard to see. When I first saw this questions I was wondering what the problem is because the code compiled just fine :)